# howto abort all incomplete multipart uploads for a bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, jq, aws-cli

Sometimes multipart uploads hang or don't complete for some reason. In that case you are stuck with orphaned parts that are tricky to remove. You can list them with:

```
aws s3api list-multipart-uploads --bucket $BUCKETNAME
```

I am looking for way to abort them all.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Assuming you have your `awscli` all setup and it'll output JSON you can use `jq` to project the needed keys with:

```
BUCKETNAME=<xxx>
aws s3api list-multipart-uploads --bucket $BUCKETNAME \
| jq -r '.Uploads[] | "--key \"\(.Key)\" --upload-id \(.UploadId)"' \
| while read -r line; do
    eval "aws s3api abort-multipart-upload --bucket $BUCKETNAME $line";
done
```

Answer (score 23):

If you are doing multipart uploading, you can do the cleanup form S3 Management console too.

a) Open your S3 bucket

b) Switch to **Management Tab**

c) Click **Add Lifecycle Rule**

d) Now type **rule name** on first step and check the **Clean up incomplete multipart uploads** checkbox. Now you an type the number of days to keep incomplete parts too.

That's it. You can see these steps in attached screen shot too.

[image: Steps to add rule]

Comment: Riz one question: If today(13 August) I set multipart cleanup rule (1 day). Then will this rule remove the object that is created before 1day (10 August)?

Answer (score 6):

Here is my oneliner, that will abort ALL multipart uploads regardless of status, assuming that you don't have any spaces in your key / filename.

```
BUCKETNAME=<xxx>;aws s3api list-multipart-uploads --bucket $BUCKETNAME --query 'Uploads[].[Key, UploadId]' --output text | awk  '{print "aws s3api abort-multipart-upload --upload-id "$2" --bucket $BUCKETNAME --key " $1 " & wait"}{}' | bash
```

Answer (score 5):

You can alternatively use [Minio Client aka mc](https://github.com/minio/mc) It is Open Source and compatible with AWS S3.

To list all the incomplete upload on a associated bucket.

```
$ mc ls -I s3/mybucketname
```

To remove all incomplete uploads to a associated S3 bucket.

```
$ mc rm -I -r --force s3/mybucketname
```

I = incomplete
r = recursive
f = with force option

Hope it helps.

Disclaimer : I work for [Minio](https://minio.io).

Answer (score 4):

You can set up lifecycle rules to automatically purge those after some amount of time. Here's a blog post demonstrating how to do it in the console:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/s3-lifecycle-management-update-support-for-multipart-uploads-and-delete-markers/

To do this in boto3:

```
import boto3


s3 = boto3.client('s3')
try:
    lifecycle = s3.get_bucket_lifecycle(Bucket='bucket')
except ClientError:
    lifecycle = {'Rules': []}
lifecycle['Rules'].append({
    'ID': 'PruneAbandonedMultipartUploads',
    'Status': 'Enabled',
    'Prefix': '',
    'AbortIncompleteMultipartUpload': {
        'DaysAfterInitiation': 7
    }
})
s3.put_bucket_lifecycle(Bucket='bucket', LifecycleConfiguration=lifecycle)
```

Adding that configuration in the cli would be much the same:

```
$ aws s3api get-bucket-lifecycle --bucket bucket > lifecycle.json
# Edit the lifecycle, adding the same configuration as in the boto3 sample
$ aws s3api put-bucket-lifecycle --bucket bucket --lifecycle-configuration file://lifecycle.json
```

If you have no lifecycle policy on your bucket, `get-bucket-lifecycle` will raise a `ClientError`. A robust implementation would make sure the right error is returned.

A policy only with that configuration would look like so:

```
{
    "Rules": [
        {
            "ID": "PruneAbandonedMultipartUpload",
            "Status": "Enabled",
            "AbortIncompleteMultipartUpload": {
                "DaysAfterInitiation": 7
            }
        }
    ]
}
```